# SwiftUI - localized accessibility label

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization, accessibility, localizable.strings

I have the following code in SwiftUI and I want to translate accessibility label from English to Polish:

```
Text("Example")
.accessibilityLabel("Color: \(color.description)")
```

And I have such translations in Localizable.strings file:

```
/* Color: color.description */
"Color: %@" = "Kolor: %@";

/* Color */
"blue" = "niebieski";
```

I've tested this with VoiceOver and it reads:
"Kolor: blue"
But should read:
"Kolor: niebieski"

Which means that color.description ("blue" in my case) wasn't translated to "niebieski". Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it :) It's quite simple.

Here is a working code:

```
Text("Example")
  .accessibilityLabel("Color")
  .accessibilityValue(LocalizedStringKey(Color.blue.description))
```

And if color value is from a variable (like in the original question), it will be:

```
Text("Example")
  .accessibilityLabel("Color")
  .accessibilityValue(LocalizedStringKey(color.description))
```

What is important is to use **localizedString(value:)**.
And I've separated accessibilityLabel to separate accessibilityLabel and accessibilityValue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `NSLocalizedString` to localize your string.

So In your case you should be using

```
Text("Example")
.accessibilityLabel(String(format: NSLocalizedString("Color: %@", comment: ""),
 color.description))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just tested, but it doesn't work and still reads "Kolor: blue". Still doesn't use color's translation I've provided in Localizable.strings file :/

Comment: @mallow I think you still need to localize the color.description and get the localized value.

Comment: But I have translation for color in the Localizable.strings file. Or do I need something more?