# VoiceOver on iOS reads our widget using english voice

Tags: ios, localization, widget, voiceover, widgetkit

We have newly created a Widget using WidgetKit for our app. The widget is localized in Norwegian and English, and localization works for the texts in the widget, the correct text is used based on what language set for the iPhone.

But when I turn on VoiceOver, the voice pronounces the words in English, even if the phone is set to Norwegian, and Norwegian texts is shown in the widget.

I find it wierd that the localization works, but that VoiceOver doesnt understand to read it in Norwegian. I tested other widgets, and there VoiceOver pronounces the words in Norwegian. This also works fine in our main app.

Have anybody experienced this before? Anybody have a clue to what we need to change in the widget to get it working properly?

Comment: check this link may be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71481195/swiftui-localized-accessibility-label

Comment: No, that was about localization of strings, and as I write, the strings are localized correctly in the UI. 

The problem we have is that VoiceOver pronounce the read-out in English, even if the words are localized in Norwegian, and Norwegian is set as language on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I just needed to add a InfoPlist.strings file in the widget and localize it (in Norwegian and English in our case). We have no strings in Info.plist that needs translation, so the InfoPlist.strings file have no content. But I guess iOS needs it to be in place to understand what languages to support for VoiceOver.